# Mule ESB Database connector (JDBC) error:

Tags: eclipse, mule, esb

I have a Database connector using the "Generic Database Configuration" 
(In other words, JDBC as opposed to MySQL).

The test connection works, and I am connecting to DB2 when I execute the program, but I am having difficulty with the configuration of the `SELECT` statement

What I am trying to achieve is something like this (which works well within the Command Line Processor

```
SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM ACCOUNT
```

So when I click on the Database Connector and go to the database tab below, I see the following

```
Connector Information:  Generic Database Configuration
Operation:              Select

Query
   Type:                   Parameterized 
    Parameterized Query:   ACCTNUM FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ACCTNUM = '11111'
```

When I run this as a Mule app, and send a http burst to it, I get the following:

```
C:\curl>curl http://localhost:8081
Query type must me '[SELECT, STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL]' but was 'DDL' (java.lang.Ill
egalArgumentException). Message payload is of type: String
```

So I suspect I did not set up the query correctly, so I tried the following:

```
Connector Information:  Generic Database Configuration
Operation:              Select

Query
   Type:                   Parameterized 
   Parameterized Query:    SELECT ACCTNUM FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ACCTNUM = '11111'
```

This time I got the following error

```
C:\curl>curl http://localhost:8081
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=INSTUID.ACCOUNT, DRIVER=3.
63.123 (com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException). Message payload is of type:
String
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Mule 3.5 and the new Database connector ... Try this :-

```
<db:select config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM ACCOUNT]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
```